# Ng-Zorro submenu cut text

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using NG-Zorro in an Angular project and I have a problem with the submenu texts, and if they're too long they get cut off and don't look complete.

I've tried forcing the CSS but I can't get the full text to display.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
<ul nz-menu nzMode="horizontal">
    <li nz-submenu nzTitle="Submenu" nzIcon="audit">
        <ul>
            <li nz-menu-item>OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION</li>
            <li nz-menu-item>OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION</li>
            <li nz-menu-item>OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION</li>
            <li nz-menu-item>OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION</li>
            <li nz-menu-item>OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION OPTION</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Submenu cut text]

Comment: This is really not good practice. And it makes ui unexpected.

Comment: Tell you to the client. They need long texts and they are the ones who pay. :'(

Comment: Do you need this for all menu items of your full app ? @JacinMontava

Comment: @GRD for all menu items.

Comment: But, You had told that you have found out solution in your previous comment which was deleted by you. Can you explain about this ?

Comment: I found a solution but it doesn't work for me since by including a select inside the app the modified class affects that select and the menu dropdown no longer works correctly. The problem is that the html elements are generated automatically and the name changes and it may be `div#cdk-overlay-0` or `div#cdk-overlay-1`

Comment: If you add a select it does not display the options correctly. I'm trying many things but I can't get anything to work :(

Comment: in demo its working correctly. Check out style.css file in demo.

Comment: I forgot the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atvvqo-3zwgvt?file=src%2Fstyles.css